# Trouble loading content on template from class in django

Tags: python, django, templates

`article.html` is displaying `{% block homeblock %}`  but all the

`{{entertainment.'suffix'}}` stuff in `{% block articlecontent %}` is not being

displayed.I can't understand why it does'nt work in this block while it is working in all the other blocks

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from entertainment.models import Entertainmentblog

class ListView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'entertainment/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
   slug = None
   id = None

def get_queryset(self):
   return Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]

class LatestArticleMixin(object):

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(LatestArticleMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        context['latest_article_list'] = Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]
    except:
        pass
    return context  


class DetailView(LatestArticleMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Entertainmentblog
    template_name = 'entertainment/article.html'
```

And This is my template `article.html`

```
{% extends "articlebase.html" %}

{% block articlecontent %}
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% else %}
<div id="art-title">
<h1 class="art-title-main">{{ entertainment.title1 }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="date_time_header"><p>{{entertainment.posted}}<p></div>

<div class="articleBody" ><img src="/static/images/rf.jpg" alt="RF"  >
<div class="article-text">
{{ entertainment.body}}
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block homeblock %}
{% include "entertainment/article-index.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

this is the `articlebase.html` file

```
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
{% block articlecontent %}{% endblock %}

<div class="articles">
<div class="container-more">
<h2 class="title">More</h2>
</div>
{% block homeblock %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is `article.html` is displaying `{% block homeblock %}`  but all the

`{{entertainment.'suffix'}}` stuff in `{% block articlecontent %}` is not being

displayed.the image is being displayed because of the `img` tag but the rest of the article

is not.Help?

Comment: Do you have an "articlecontent" block in the "articlebase" template?

Comment: Could you include `articlebase.html` in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not passing `entertainment` into the context. DetailView uses `object` as name of the object in template. Either use `object` instead of the `entertainment` in template or set `context_object_name` attribute on your DetailView class to value 'entertainment'.